# Object Edges Won't Scale

Tags: edit-mode, edges

Was trying to make house. Tried to scale one side of a rectangle by selecting the edges/vertices and scaling them but it seems it won't scale in the axis I want.

Tried to set settings to default and reinstalled it, the problem persists.

Do you know why does this happens? 
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few things wrong with this: 1) you are selecting vertices, not faces. This would be so much easier to do by selecting faces. 2) You are trying to scale the face along the X axis. Since it can not get thicker along that axis, to move it, *transform* it on the X axis, don't scale it.

Comment: THANK YOU SO MUCH. <33333333

Answer (score 0):

Never mind, find why it wasn't working.

Once the 4 vertices are selected. Press G to transform, then select the axis where you wanna scale [X, Y, or Z].